# Distinguish directory name or path to the directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a shell script which takes a directory-name or path to the directory command-line, and create that directory. If I want to identify the argument is a valid path or only a directory-name, how can I achieve this? As if a directory-name is passed then that directory will be created in the location from where the script is being executed, and if it is a path then the directory will be created on that path. So this distinction is necessary for my script.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Why do you even need to know? `mkdir -p X` works fine when X is just `foo` and when it is `/tmp/foo`

Comment: From your description I don't think there are any two separate cases, because directory name is valid path to (possibly not yet existing) directory of that name in current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir=$(dirname -- "$1")

if test "$dir" != '.'; then
    echo 'Path'
else
    echo 'Directory'
fi
```

Comment: @Gilles and @Timofey Stolbov thanks both of you. This technique is working. Can you please tell me why are you using dirname -- "$1" insteed of dirname $1? I didn't find any resource over internet, perhaps I didn't use proper search query, to know this particular usage of test command, can you please explain or point me to some website?

Comment: @Tapas: The `--` are necessary if the argument might begin with a `-`, because otherwise `dirname` would interpret that as an option. The double quotes are needed in case the argument contains special character (whitespace or `\[?*`), because otherwise the shell would split it into words and do globbing (wildcard matching). General rule: always put double quotes around variable substitutions.

Comment: @Timofey: I don't think your code does what's intended. For example, it treats `./foo` as a “Directory”, same as `foo`.

Comment: @Tapas: Just look in the `test` manual (`man test`), or in your shell's manual (`test` is a built-in command in pretty much every shell). This form tests whether the two strings `$dir` and `.` are different.

Comment: @Gilles As I understand script must not create another directories in current dir. So treating `foo` and `./foo` as equal case is right.

Comment: @Timofey: Uh? I can't think of a use case where `foo` is the same as `./foo` but not the same as `././foo` or `../bar/foo` or `qux/../foo` or `/wibble/bar/foo` (where the current directory is `/wibble/bar`).

Answer (score 1):

Some programs treat arguments with a trailing '/' differently. Consider:

```
./foo x

./foo x/
```

However, I would encourage the use of a "tag"/"option" if applicable as the above is a very subtle detail to overlook. (Think of the users!).

```
./foo -p x

./foo --path=x

./foo x
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, nor convinced you need to make this distinction: `mkdir -- "$1"` creates a directory no matter how you present the name to it.

To test whether the first argument is a simple directory name with no path component (e.g. `foo` but not `foo/bar` or `/abso/lute`), test whether it contains a `/`:

```
case "$1" in
  */*) echo "contains multiple path components";;
  *) echo "no slash, just a base name";;
esac
```

To test whether the first argument is a relative path or an absolute path, test whether it starts with `/`:

```
case "$1" in
  /*) echo "absolute";;
  *) echo "relative";;
esac
```

By the way that this applies whether you're considering a file or a directory.

Comment: thanks. I had a thought about arg.contains('/'). say, x=abc and y=$(echo $x | grep [/]) then echo ${#y} returns 0.